# Prove that Z0^N-1 = 1/Z0. Express all answers in polar form.

Tags: complex-numbers

```
Let Z0 = e^j(2pi)/N. Prove that Z0^N-1 = 1/Z0
```

Don't know how to start this. Any help is appreciated!

Z0^N-1 =

1/Z0 =Z0^-1

=e^-1j2pi/N

=e^-1 * e^j2piN

= ??

Not sure what to do

Comment: There is only one step in the proof. We would like to see you effort: what you did and what you are stuck at.

Comment: Here's what I tried:
Z0^N-1 = 1/Z0
=Z0^-1
=e^-1j2pi/N
=e^-1 * e^j2piN
= ??

Comment: Check edit of question to see what I tried ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^{ab} \neq x^a\cdot x^b$. Rather, $x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$, and $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$.

Now, $z_0 = e^{j2\pi/N} \implies z_0^{N-1} = e^{j 2\pi(N-1)/N} = e^{j2\pi}e^{-j2\pi/N}=1/e^{j2\pi/N}=1/z_0.$
Here, I have used $e^{j 2\pi} = 1$.